# Set image as base, small and thumbnail

Tags: magento-1.7, import, image, avs-fastsimpleimport

So I am constructing an import array with details and using AvS_FastSimpleImport to do the importing work. Here is the relevant code:

```
$fileName = Mage::getBaseDir()."/".Mage::getStoreConfig(C4B_XmlImport_Model_Catalog_Importer::XML_PATH_IMAGE_IMPORT_DIRECTORY).$imageName;
            if (file_exists($fileName)) {
                $addImage = $defaultImportEntry;
                $addImage['sku'] = '';
                $addImage['_media_image'] = $imageName;
                $addImage['_media_attribute_id'] = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getAttributeId();
                $addImage['_media_is_disabled'] = 0;
                $addImage['_media_position'] = $imgCounter;
                $addImage['_media_lable'] = $imageName;
                if(!$isAssociatedProduct && $currentNumber == 1) {
                    $addImage['image'] = $fileName;
                    $addImage['small_image'] = $fileName;
                    $addImage['thumbnail'] = $fileName;
                    }
            }
```

The second `if` statement is entered only for specific images (as you can see). On these images I want the radio buttons of **Base Image**, **Small Image**, and **Thumbnail** to be set, but apparently it doesn't work.

Here's a tutorial document I was reading: http://www.integer-net.de/download/ImportExport_EN.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in `image`, `small_image` and `thumbnail` should be the same as in `_media_image`. You should use `$imageName` instead of `$fileName` there.

Answer (score -1):

you have to do only one think

Just Set the Store Id when you save your product.

```
foreach($image_array as $single_image) {
    $img_counter++;    
    if ($img_counter == 1) {
        $img_save_mode = array('image','small_image','thumbnail');
    } else {
        $img_save_mode = array();
    }    
    $upper_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' . DS ;
    $filepath = $upper_path . $single_image;    
    if ( file_exists($filepath) ) {
    try {
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath, $img_save_mode , false , false);        
        $product->setStoreId(0);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    } else {
        echo "Product does not have an image or the path is incorrect. Path was: {$filepath}<br/>";
    }
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: I work with `SimpleXMLElement` objects (i.e. my `$product` obj) so I cannot use `addImagToMediaGallery()`.

Comment: then just set store id in your product Object

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what role does the store id play here. Can you elaborate why I need it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372969/how-to-find-out-what-my-store-id-is

Refer this

Comment: This still does not help. I simply do not see the place to use the store id.

Comment: This answer doesn't fit to the question. As stated, FastSimpleImport is used, not product models.